# Splitting Input With Newlines and Spaces Into Array of Numbers Gives Array with extra 0 at end

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have some input that looks like:

```
2
2 2
2
2 0
0 5
3 3
3 5
1 1 1
3 0 0
1 10 0
```

With (sometimes) an extra newline at the end. I have been splitting this data into an array of numbers using `var b = this.data.replace(/\n/g, " ").split(/[\s,]+/).map(Number);` where the above input is stored in `this.data`. and `b` is the new array. When there is no newline at the end, this works fine. However, if I have the newline at the end, I end up with an extra 0 at the end. It seems like the following is happening:

- `\n` characters get replaced by spaces
- list is split on spaces -- when there's a `\n` at the end, there is a (blank) element at the end of this list
- `map(Number)` interprets the last (empty) element as a `0`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `Map(x=>parseFloat(x))` instead ... or  do what the next comment does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the string before working with it

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

```js
const str = `
2
2 2
2
2 0
0 5
3 3
3 5
1 1 1
3 0 0
1 10 0
`

const result = str.trim().split(/\s|\n/).map(Number)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Match sequence of digits, and map them to numbers:

```js
const str = `
2
2 2
2
2 0
0 5
3 3
3 5
1 1 1
3 0 0
1 10 0
`

const result = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm using match, and not split.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before the `.map()`

```js
const str = `
2
2 2
2
2 0
0 5
3 3
3 5
1 1 1
3 0 0
1 10 0

`

const result = str.split(/\n|\s/).filter(Boolean).map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, this task can be done also with [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const str = `
2
2 2
2
2 0
0 5
3 3
3 5
1 1 1
3 0 0
1 10 0

`

const result = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, in a tricky way using the [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
const str = `
2
2 2
2
2 0
0 5
3 3
3 5
1 1 1
3 0 0
1 10 0

`
let result = [];
str.replace(/\d+/g, m => (result.push(+m), m));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```